# Linked List C - create a Head when none is existing

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement a singly linked list in C and have trouble to create the Head node.

my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE{
    int value;
    struct NODE* next;
}node;

int append(node* head, int val){
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("Head is NULL");
        head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(head == NULL){
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        head->value = val;
        head->next = NULL;
    } else {
        printf("Head is not NULL");
        while(head->next != NULL){
            head = head->next;
        }
        head = malloc(sizeof(node));
        head->value = val;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(){

    node* head = NULL;

    append(head, 10);
    append(head, 5);
    append(head, 7);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

when adding nodes, memory for the head should be allocated and then filled with the arguments, if it does not already exist. I can't figure out, why the Head always stays NULL.

Can anybody explain this to me?
I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do some research about *pass by value* and *pass by reference*, and learn how to *emulate* pass by reference in C. Or simply *return* the new `head`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`head` is always `NULL`, because you are not modifying it, you are modifying its copied value instead.

In `main()`, do this:

`append(&head, 10);  // Modify head itself and not its copied value`

Change the function signature to this:

`int append(node** head, int val)`

inside the function `append()` replace `head` with `*head` everywhere

There is one more problem with your code. In `append()` , there is no need of the `while` loop, since you will be permanently shifting the `head` to the end. You should not do this because `head` should always point to "head" of the linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct NODE
{
  int value;
  struct NODE *next;
} node;

int
append (node **head, int val)
{
  if (*head == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Head is NULL");
      *head = malloc (sizeof (node));
      if (*head == NULL)
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
      (*head)->value = val;
      (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
  else
    {
      printf ("Head is not NULL");

      node * temp = malloc (sizeof (node));
      temp->value = val;
      temp->next = *head;
      *head = temp;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int
main ()
{

  node *head = NULL;

  append (&head, 10);
  append (&head, 5);
  append (&head, 7);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Head is NULLHead is not NULLHead is not NULL
```